laptop lid driver-less USB webcam with good image quality
I have previously used a Sony A5100 DSLR as a webcam which provided excellent image quality. I was also very happy with the built-in webcam of the MacBook Pro M2.
Sadly for work I have to use a cheap Dell laptop with poor webcam.
I would like recommendations that meet the following requirements:

attaches to the top of the laptop lid
works entirely via USB-A or USB-C
does NOT require drivers or software
by image quality I don't mean resolution, I mean clarity, colours and skin tones, not blowing the image with strong background lights, not grainy in lower light

(I know small optics are not ideal)
